# low level caching using memory_store on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku

I'm trying something like this

> config.cache_store = :memory_store

then

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base


  def self.cached_list(id)
     Rails.cache.fetch("post_list") do
       Post.order("created_at").all
     end
  end
```

then call

```
Post.cached_list
```

I put a simple statistics on the live site with

```
@caches = Rails.cache.instance_variable_get(:@data).keys
```

and do something like on the view

```
<%@caches.each do |cache|%>
 <%=cache%>
<%end%>
```

The problem is sometimes, the the cache_lists gets cleared instantly.
My hypothesis is that,  heroku automatically clears my cache every after sometime.
I am wrong? or is there anything wrong why I print all the cache keys?

---

after much experimentation, I found out my answer. The reason is because the memory_store is local to each dyno and each dyno "cannot and don't know other dyno".
For example there's a cache "post_list" in DYNO_1, if a request is handled by DYNO_2, then the cache will miss.